# XCRUD : how to insert html?

Tags: php

I use an old library xcrud (php) from https://codecanyon.net/item/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud

And I fo try to insert some HTML tags, but they are all stripped.

Any idea on how to avoid stripping html tags ?

Regards

Comment: that codecanyon link returns a 404

Comment: But, if you have the code yourself downloaded into your application (which you must have, I would think), you are probably looking for uses of the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function - its job is to remove HTML and PHP tags from strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new Version of Xcrud that could work better for your need. You can find it here www.xcrud.net and they still offer support.

To also avoid the tags from being stripped, you can use tinyMCE by specifying a column to be text.